# Batch insert into StorageMap without iterations

Tags: substrate-node-template, storagemap, batch, iteration

Is there a way to do batch inset operation into a StorageMap without iteration or using a Vec[] type or best workarounds. and if its not whats the reason for not supporting this?

For example there's a method available remove_all()

Thanks!

Comment: For what are you trying to use batch insertions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no such method. I think it could exist, but it would need some refactor to directly pass a database transaction to the backend. Normally we dont have many batch insertions in a runtime, so it has been not that big of a problem.

Batch operations are a foot-gun for parachains, since they need to pay close attention to their weight consumption. This also applies to `remove_all` and should always be used with a upper limit to its iteration size.